# mongodb : How to get limit number of document sorted by field of subarray?

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb collection is like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d93fa1a5261dfb4940f166f"),
    "hash" : "1",
    "transfers" : [ 
        {
            "symbol" : "aba",
            "from" : "sh",
            "to" : "jh",
            "amount" : 123.0
        }, 
        {
            "symbol" : "bob",
            "from" : "yh",
            "to" : "sh",
            "amount" : 12321.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d93fac65261dfb4940f1670"),
    "hash" : "2",
    "transfers" : [ 
        {
            "symbol" : "cbc",
            "from" : "sh",
            "to" : "jh",
            "amount" : 222.0
        }, 
        {
            "symbol" : "bob",
            "from" : "yh",
            "to" : "sh",
            "amount" : 333.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d93fead5261dfb4940f1672"),
    "hash" : "3",
    "transfers" : [ 
        {
            "symbol" : "bob",
            "from" : "sh",
            "to" : "jh",
            "amount" : 333.0
        }, 
        {
            "symbol" : "bob",
            "from" : "yh",
            "to" : "sh",
            "amount" : 444.0
        }
    ]
}
```

## What I want to do is extracting limited number of sorted collection based on `amount` field of subarray `transfers`

When I tried to with this command

```
db.getCollection('sh_test_transaction').find({"transfers.symbol":"bob"}).sort({'transfers.amount':-1}).limit(2)
```

it returns like below

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d93fa1a5261dfb4940f166f"),
    "hash" : "1",
    "block_number" : 1.0,
    "transfers" : [ 
        {
            "symbol" : "aba",
            "from" : "sh",
            "to" : "jh",
            "amount" : 123.0
        }, 
        {
            "symbol" : "bob",
            "from" : "yh",
            "to" : "sh",
            "amount" : 12321.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d93fead5261dfb4940f1672"),
    "hash" : "3",
    "block_number" : 3.0,
    "transfers" : [ 
        {
            "symbol" : "bob",
            "from" : "sh",
            "to" : "jh",
            "amount" : 333.0
        }, 
        {
            "symbol" : "bob",
            "from" : "yh",
            "to" : "sh",
            "amount" : 444.0
        }
    ]
}
```

But the result what I want  is like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d93fa1a5261dfb4940f166f"),
    "hash" : "1",
    "block_number" : 1.0,
    "transfers" : [ 
        {
            "symbol" : "bob",
            "from" : "yh",
            "to" : "sh",
            "amount" : 12321.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d93fead5261dfb4940f1672"),
    "hash" : "3",
    "block_number" : 3.0,
    "transfers" : [ 
        {
            "symbol" : "bob",
            "from" : "yh",
            "to" : "sh",
            "amount" : 444.0
        }
    ]
}
```

(I don't need to change original data)

Since I'm newbie at mongodb world, I need your help.

Thank you in advance~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the highest two amounts over all entries? That sounds like you need to use the aggregate framework. But you also want them embedded in the original document? Without the other transfers that might be in the document?

I don't remember the exact commands, but i would try like this:

- first you need to extract the transfers and maybe add the surrounding document inside, that's maybe a flatMap and a map combined? so A{B,C} becomes B{A}, C{A}
- then you need to sort by amount
- then you limit the results to two entries. but what if multiple results have the same value? that's a different
- then you revert the flatMap operation and turn C{A}, G{D} into A{C}, G{D}. here maybe you need to join if both results are in the same document, so C{A}, B{A} would become one document A{C,B} instead of two documents A{C}, A{B}
- do you even need the original document or only the transfer-part? would make the algorithm a lot easier. or you just store the id of the outer document and look it up later.

So lots of stuff to consider first before designing the aggregate function, but it is really worth it!

If you are just learning, try writing a normal query that gets all entries and does all that stuff by hand, checks every element against the highest two. compare how much faster the aggregate is.

happy coding!

A first start would be like this, depending on your requirements you'll have to do more voodoo :)

```
db.sh_test_transaction.aggregate([
   { $match: { "transfers.symbol": "bob" } },
   { $unwind : "$transfers" },
   { $sort : { "transfers.amount" : -1 } },
   { limit: 2 },
....
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
It is really helpful for me. 
Finally I did like this
`db.getCollection('sh_test_transaction').aggregate([
{$unwind: "$transfers"},
{$match: { "transfers.symbol": "bob" } },
{$sort:{"transfers.amount": -1}},
{$limit: 2}])`